# TempData[] does not work on the IIS server, but works on the local computer

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

I have a controller that outputs a message and then redirects to Index(). The problem is that the code works properly on the local machine, and when publishing on IIS does not want to output a message, and the rest of the code works correctly. Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileExcel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    #region check
                    if (fileExcel == null)
                    {
                        TempData["AlertMessage"] = "aboba";
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                    }
                    #endregion
                ...

                }
            }
        }
```

IIS version 10.0

I tried to replace TempData with Session, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, TempData is stored in session state, which means that the web application must have sessions enabled. If TempData is disabled, it will not work as expected.

You can check if session state is enabled in your application Web.config file by looking for the following line:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" />
```